# Even though I am setting port number to 2587 getting error Could not connect to SMTP host: email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, port: 25

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, smtp, jakarta-mail, amazon-ses

static final String HOST = "email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com";
static final int PORT = 2587;

```
private static Properties getProperties() {


    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", HOST);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT);
```

}

Comment: should I take port as a String or int is fine?

Comment: Did you make any of these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ.html#commonmistakes)?

Comment: Actually that datatype change resolved my problem.. In Property all variables should be String only.

Comment: That should only be an issue with older versions of JavaMail.  The current version will do the data type conversions.